# Why changing the table collation in mysql breaks with unique index violation?

Tags: mysql

Problem:

Let's say that table `customers (id, name, email, .. )` is encoded using utf-8 (utf8_general_ci collation).

This table also has a unique key constraint on column `email`.

When trying to change the collation to utf8mb4 using
`ALTER TABLE customers CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;`,
some entries cause the unique index constraint to flare up, because they are considered duplicates.

Example:

```
row1: (1, "strauss" "strauss@email.com")
row2: (10, "Strauss" "strauß@email.com")
```

same happens if two emails differ only by a zero width space char.

Tested with mysql version 5.7.20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In German, `ß` is considered basically equal to `ss`.

While the `xxx_unicode_ci` collation respects that, the `xxx_general_ci` does not, so you switched from a collation that considers "straus@email.com" not the same as "strauß@email.com" to one that does.

Actually, `xxx_general_ci` treats `ß` and `s` the same, so it would complain about "straus@email.com" and "strauß@email.com" instead.

See the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html#charset-unicode-sets-general-versus-unicode):

> **_general_ci Versus _unicode_ci Collations**

> For any Unicode character set, operations performed using the xxx_general_ci collation are faster than those for the xxx_unicode_ci collation. For example, comparisons for the utf8_general_ci collation are faster, but slightly less correct, than comparisons for utf8_unicode_ci. The reason is that utf8_unicode_ci supports mappings such as expansions; that is, when one character compares as equal to combinations of other characters. For example, ß is equal to ss in German and some other languages. utf8_unicode_ci also supports contractions and ignorable characters. utf8_general_ci is a legacy collation that does not support expansions, contractions, or ignorable characters. It can make only one-to-one comparisons between characters.